# NFT transfers not showing in Etherscan

Tags: solidity, etherscan, nft

I am developing a nft contract.

but the issue is that nft transfer are not showing in Mumbai Polygonscan.

I know the total supply is given by totalSupply function.
But where Etherscan gets Transfers and nr of Token holder information  ?

[image]

I checked event transfer and is all fine... perhaps it gets from event tranfers.

Comment: Hey, have you verified the contract?

Comment: i didnt verified the contract, but i see other non-verified contracts is showing such information

Comment: of couse, it was with the aim of debugging

Comment: Can you provide transaction link in the block explorer?